# How can we hide div if it is blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Example:** http://partnerswealth.advisorproducts.com/home

http://mah.advisorproducts.com/home

**Requirement:**

I want to hide Left and Right div or Box when it is empty.

**Below is the HTML code i am using:**

```
<div class="Box secondaryBackground">
<div class="innerBox containerBackground">
<h2> </h2>
<div class="innerBoxContent">
<div class="eNews"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Below is the js i am using** - and trying to add **DispNone** class only in that Box class div whose **innerBoxContent** children div is empty.

So i just want to add class in Box class div if **innerBoxContent** class div children like eNews is empty.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    str = $('.innerBoxContent > div').text();
    if ($.trim(str) === "") {
        $('.innerBox').parent().addClass('DispNone');
    }
    else {
        $('.innerBox').parent().removeClass('DispNone');
    }
});
```

Can we modify this code?

Right now its adding class to all innerBox div but i want only for those div whose last child element is empty like .eNews not for all.
Thanks
Sushil

Comment: What do you want? You have any problem with your code?

Comment: What event or action is causing the div to become empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to go throuh your elements like this:

```
$('.innerBoxContent').each(function() {
    var noContent = 0;
    var count = $(this).children().length;
    $(this).children().each(function() {
        if ($(this).html == '') {
            ++noContent;
        }
    });
    if (noContent === count) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

The above takes into consideration that each innerBoxContent can have several children and that some might be empty, and some might not.

It's untested and I wouldn'y be surprised if there is a smarter way to do it :)

Comment: Thanks Dude you gave me an idea to resolve this see what i have done in js code.

Answer (score 1):

Why use JS? Use it to fallback if the browser is IE8 or if you use feature detection ( like [modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) recommended) and find that the :empty selector is not defined or available.

CSS has a [:empty pseudo-class](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-empty) that you can use.

> This pseudo-class matches elements that have no children. Element
>   nodes and non-empty text nodes are considered to be children; empty
>   text nodes, comments, and processing instructions don’t count as
>   children. A text node is considered empty if it has a data length of
>   zero; so, for example, a text node with a single space isn’t empty.

So, if you had something like:

```
.innerBoxContent:empty {
display: none;
}
```

And you had

```
<div class="innerBoxContent"></div>
```

It would work. However, if you had:

```
<div class="innerBoxContent">
  <div class="eNews">
  </div>
</div>
```

The selector would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just count innerBoxContent  children?

```
if ($('.innerBoxContent > div').length) {
    $('.innerBox').parent().removeClass('DispNone');
} else {
    $('.innerBox').parent().addClass('DispNone');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".eNews").each(function(index, element){
    if($(element).html() == ""){
        $(element).parent().hide();
    }
)};
```

Comment: if you're using the same jquery element more than once - it should be cached. In your example you don't even need get the jquery elem, e.g.:
element.style.display = (element.innerHTML.length ? 'block' : 'none');

Answer (score 0):

i would say something like

```
$('.innerBoxContent > div').each(function() {
                                      if( this.html() == "" ) {
                                         this.parent().hide();
                                      }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) function.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        str = $('.innerBoxContent > div').text();
        if ($.trim(str) === "") {
            $('.innerBox').parent().toggle();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content in the `innerBoxContent` is present and then some action removes the content from that section, then you should do your showing/hiding on that event and not attempt to fire an event that runs on all events.

If the content is only loaded from the server, then you should just apply a class on it at that point and not rely on JavaScript to do your initial presentation style for you.

A number of results help with the JavaScript but how the content is added and removed is where the script needs to be placed.

Alternatively to chaining the showing/hiding to whatever event changes the content, you can setting an event emitter and then just wire up the code via an event system instead.